# create variable with name of other variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, loops

It is difficult to find a title for this :D

I have this code:

```
data=( "slots" "npcs" )
for i in "${data[@]}"
do
  "$i"=$(mysql_exec "SELECT $i FROM orders WHERE order_id = $order") # slots returns 5 and npcs returns 1
done
```

In the loop, I want to create a variable with the name of content from `$i`.
So it should create a variable named `slots (content: 5)` and `npcs (content: 1)`

I hope you understand my problem :P

Errors:

```
./install: Line 16: slots=5: command not found.
./install: Line 16: npcs=1: command not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `declare` command to create variable names on the fly.

```
data=( "slots" "npcs" )
for i in "${data[@]}"
do
  declare "$i=$(mysql_exec "SELECT $i FROM orders WHERE order_id = $order")" # slots returns 5 and npcs returns 1
done
```

The `read` command can also be used in conjunction with process substation

```
read $i < <(mysql_exec "SELECT $i FROM orders WHERE order_id = $order")
```

Consider, though, whether either approach is really superior to simply writing

```
grab_from_sql () {
   mysql_exec "SELECT $1 FROM orders WHERE order_id = $2"
}
slots=$(grab_from_sql slots $order)
npcs=$(grab_from_sql npcs $order)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash 4 you can use associative arrays:

```
data=(slots npcs)
declare -A res
for i in "${data[@]}"; do
  res[i]=$(mysql …)
done
```

If you don't have a shell that supports associative arrays, you aren't going to be able to do this well using a shell. Consider using a scripting language. You *can* use `awk`, which has support for associative arrays if all else fails. Use the `system` function in `awk` to execute the `mysql` command.